# Why here the tag question doesn't match the rules?

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

I saw this example in [Long Man dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/taunt):

> ‘And he’ll believe you, will he?’ Maria taunted.

Why here the rule of tag question is not cared for? Shouldn't it be:

> He won't believe you, will he?

Or

> He will believe you, won't he?

Comment: You append a "tag question" to a statement when you're expecting ***confirmation***. In the cited context, Maria obviously ***doesn't*** think "he" will believe whoever she's talking to, so it's not a tag question anyway. The fact that she ***taunted*** with those words is evidence that she really doesn't expect the addressee to reply *"Of course he'll believe me!* - she'd more likely expect a reply like *"No, I don't suppose he will"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True tag questions are used to check understanding:

> That's a dog, isn't it?

The speaker expresses an opinion, and then asks the question, negated.

This implies that the speaker believes it is a dog.

But sometimes the speaker will use irony.

> What!?  That's a *dog*?

(Irony is very hard to indicate in text!)  The meaning here is "I don't think that's a dog."

You would tag this with a positive tag

> What!?  That's a *dog*, is it? Really?

Something similar is indicated here.
The speaker says "He'll believe you" ironically, meaning "I don't think He'll believe you".  The irony is confirmed by the tag question being positive.

> He'll believe you, won't he?  "I think and hope that he will believe you."

> He'll believe you, will he? "I don't think that he'll believe you."

Comment: I'm not big on terminological exactitude, but isn't a tag question *by definition* the "opposite" of the preceding assertion? That's to say, it always either *Positive assertion + Negating tag* or *Negating assertion + Positive tag*. I'm not sure *Negating + Negating* normally occurs anyway, but it seems to me that *Positive + Positive* normally expresses "disbelief", rather than seeking confirmation.

Comment: The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language simply says 'A tag is a short interrogative which may be negative of positive' and refers to 'negative polarity tags' (what you call 'opposite') and 'positive polarity tags'. Negative polarity is probably the default (CGEL 'much the more frequent'), but tags are not 'by definition' the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focusing on the rules, in my opinion it depends on the intended meaning of the phrase.
"He'll believe you" is a positive statement, and the tag "will he" queries it.
On the other hand, "He won't believe you" is a negative statement  and the tag "will he"? seeks to reinforce it rather than querying.

There are exceptions to almost every rule.